# Joint estimation of OLS and Logistic Model

Tags: logistic, least-squares, goodness-of-fit

I ran two equations for panel data, the Q (OLS model), the second is ERM (Logistic model), the main independent variable in equation 1 is the main dependent var in equation 2.
To solve the endogeneity problem in the first equation if I have to test the appropriateness of the join estimation of the 2 equations?

Does anyone have an idea of how to do that in R, I will be very grateful?

Xb & Xa are variable are only available in regression 1,
t & X5 variable only in reg 1,
all other in both reg,
r is dummy variable (0,1)

using Rstudio

Regr1:

```r
ols <- plm( t ~ r + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5, data=pdata, model="pooling")
```

Reg 2:

```r
log <- glm(factor(r) ~ X2 + X3  + X4 + Xa + Xb , data=pdata, 
           family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

Comment: The Stata manual for [`etregress`](https://www.stata.com/manuals/teetregress.pdf#page=23) outlines a fairly simple two-step CF estimator using augmented regression. I think that should be doable with `plm`/`glm`. At the very least, there are references to the literature that may make it easier to find an R package.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I will search more in this manual. I may find the answer. Thank you